# How to download private files from S3 by generating a link in java or javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, amazon-s3

I am trying to download a file from s3 by just clicking on href link but i didn't find any solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the AWS web / management consolve, you should be able to create an S3 bucket (with Everyone -> Read) permissions, then upload a file to it.  I have just done this, and can download the file successfully using:

```
wget https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-test-bucket-12345-chocksaway/tester
```

I am in eu-west-1 region -> my-test-bucket-12345-chocksaway is the name of my bucket -> tester is the name of the file.